# How to break a string into many variables

Tags: java

Is it possible in Java to break a `String` into many individual `int` variables?

```
String s = "1,2,3,4,5,6";
```

Like

```
int var1 = 1;

int var2 = 2;

int var3 = 3;
```

and so on.

```
Thanks
```

Comment: no, but you can **split** to string array using "," as delimiter and then convert(parse) it into array of ints

Answer (score 0, accepted):

split() method is more apt one.One of the other way is use StringTokenizer class, as follows

```
    String abc = "1,2,3,4";

    int i = 0;
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(abc,","); 
    int array[] = new int[st.countTokens()];
    while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        array[i] = Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken().toString());
        i++;
    }
```

I know your problem is already solved.But this code snippet is just to introduce use of StringTokenizer

Answer (score 4):

```
String s = "1,2,3,4,5,6";
String[] vars = s.split(",");
int [] varIn= new int[vars.lenght]

for (int i=0;i<vars.lenght;i++)
{
  varIn[i]= Integer.parseInt(vars[i]);
}
```

.

```
==> varIn[0]=1;
    varIn[1]=2;
    etc..
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot dynamically allocate the values to each variable unless you use reflection.

What you can do is [split the string on the commas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29), [convert each token into an integer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) and put these values inside a collection.

For example:

```
int[] result;
String s = "1,2,3,4,5,6";
String[] tokens = s.split(",");
result = new int[tokens.length];

for(int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++){
    result[i] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[i]);
}
```

Now you can access each value in the `result` array (perhaps by assigning `var1` to `result[1]`).

As said: you can also add it to the variables directly using reflection but that's usually a sign that your design went wrong somewhere.